# Installing a USB-A Port on D-Link DIR-300NRU B7 with Ralink RT5350F Chipset

Tags: capacitor, pcb, usb, resistors, soldering

I am writing to enquire about the installation of a  USB-A port into the existing but soldered pins on DIR-300NRU B7. The board is given below:

[image: The USB pins are located on the bottom right.]

The USB pins are located on the bottom right.

The backside of the board is the following:

First of all, the installation *can* be successfully completed (see, for instance, ptipti.ru for a guide on the related topic).

The following equipment was listed as required:

1. 4 zero-ohm resistors
2. 1 8.2 k\$\Omega\$ resistor to be soldered to R129 in the back (for the USB2.0 to work)
3. 1 capacitor, preferably 1000 \$\mu\$F with the power of 6.3 V
4. 1 capacitor of any capacity to be soldered to C209 in the back (for the USB2.0 to work)

Unfortunately, there is no comprehensible guide to soldering the USB port to this board.

The questions are:

---

Q1. Is the equipment listed necessary and sufficient? If yes, please kindly proceed to the second question. If no, what is the required equipment?

---

Q2. What capacitor in the point 4 would you recommend to use? What power of the resistor in the point 2 should be installed? Do I have to use zero-ohm resistors and why?

---

Q3. How should the USB socket be soldered? Which part of the equipment should be soldered into what pins?

---

Additional Info:

One resource mentioned "using the power source on the empty track" for some reason.

---

Added Questions:

Q*1. Could you please tell me or recommend any sources on how to connect right angle through hole socket?

---

Q*2.Would you mind telling me where the zero-ohm resistors should be soldered in? Where should the data pair be soldered in?

---

Q*3.Where should the power and ground fuse go?

---

Q*4. Could you please tell me where the capacitor given in the point 3 has to be soldered in?

---

The picture of a similar modification scheme has been found:
[image]

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q1. Is the equipment listed necessary and sufficient? If yes, please kindly proceed to the second question. If no, what is the required equipment?

Yes, that's seems to be the bare minimum required to add a USB port in the existing traces.

> Q2. What capacitor in the point 4 would you recommend to use? What power of the resistor in the point 2 should be installed? Do I have to use zero-ohm resistors and why?

C209 is a non-polarized SMD 0604 or smaller capacitor. If the original mod didn't say, I'm not sure. Try a 0.1uF, that's an average decoupling capacitor. Or look up other router USB mods for their values.

The R129 is just a signal or bootstrap resistor. And originally a smd 0604 or smaller resistor from what I can figure. It's power rating isn't really important. 0604 resistors are 0.1W. A 1/4th Watt through hole resistor would work fine.

The Zero Ohm resistors are jumpers, used to bridge a break in the data pairs or power/ground. It's recommended as the data pairs must be kept the same length or they start to have issues. The jumpers for the power fuse and ground could be bare wire.

> Q3. How should the USB socket be soldered? Which equipment should be soldered into what pins?

A standard usb through hole right angle socket can be soldered in with any regular soldering iron, using typical soldering techniques.

Comment: A de soldering tool or at least some wick might come in handy for that USB socket

Comment: Thank you for your magnificent answer! Could you please tell me or recommend any sources on how to connect right angle through hole socket? Would you mind telling me where the zero-ohm resistors should be soldered in? Where should the power and ground fuse go?

Comment: Could you please tell me where the capacitor given in the point 3 has to be soldered in?

Comment: It's a "Vertical USB A Female Socket" like http://p.globalsources.com/IMAGES/PDT/BIG/061/B0171517061.jpg You have to solder them in like any part. Alternatively, some people just take a usb extension cable and cut it in half and solder that in. Google image search "usb router mod" for examples.

Comment: And I am not responsible if you break your router which is totally possible, but the Zero ohm resistors would likely go to the spots marked R127, R128, L24 for ground by the usb drawing, and I think F1 and L25, for power. Again, This might and likely will break your router. And keep in mind you likely need Open-WRT for usb to work. See https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ptipti.ru%2Fdir-300nru-b7-замена-flash-8mb-установка-openwrt-и-внешняя-анте%2F&edit-text=&act=url

Comment: Oh @J.Tanizaki I see you were the one asking them for a picture. It seems the B7 is only a russian version of the router. It doesn't have as much info out, and no similar version in the US. From my google searches noone else has done this, but I can't read russian well enough to know. Best of luck, and remember I am giving generic advice, its possible it might break your router. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much, Passerby.  You are most helpful. Could you please tell me where the capacitor given in the point 3 has to be soldered in?

Comment: That's c213, the big circle right by the usb drawing. It's a power filter capacitor.

Comment: Thank you for your time, attention and good will, Passerby. I wonder how knowledgeable you are! Is the big yinyanglike circle the customary symbol for the power filter capacitors? Out of the personal interest, do you understand how the whole circuit works? Would you mind sharing with me your concerns about tweaking the board?

Comment: The ying yang like circle is a symbol for polarized through hole capacitors. The white part is the negative side, look at the other two green capacitors near it. See the stripe? That's the negative side, and the same type of capacitor you need. And yes, the circuit is a standard usb data and power. If you google image search for "USB Router Mod" you will see many different versions of the same mod/hack you are trying.

Comment: Passerby, thank you very much for your help! The picture of a similar modification scheme has been attached to the post. I wonder if it helps you to figure anything out. The same person on lan23.ru/forum/showthread.php?t=11103 said that he used the power source on the empty track. It seems the ground wire should be attached to R127, doesn't it? I wonder where the data pair should be attached if it is true. And what about F1 and L25? How should they be connected?

Comment: R128, R127, and L24 all go to ground. Though you could just do R127 and L24. And the empty track as I said is C213, F1, and L25.

Comment: Passerby, so how they all should be connected? Do the data + and data - pins on the USB connect to the zero-ohm resistors and then to R127 and R128? The ground pin on the USB is then connected to L24 with a wire, right? What *is* the empty track? How are F1 and L25 connected? Where does the power pin on the USB socket connect to? Do I connect the pins of the USB to anything at all other than the 4 pins on the board?

Comment: The usb connector fits into the four pins. The D+ and D- connect directly to it. F1 and L25 are zero ohm resistors or wires in my opinion and R127, R128 and L24 are also zero ohm resistors.